# VBA - Edit text in headers and footers based om XML file

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to speed up a code at work, for translating a dynamic document using VBA. The code I have works flawlessly for the main body, but does not update the header and footer of the document.

I'm at a loss as to how to get it working. I'm not fluent in VBA, and this might not be the best way to do this at all?

```
' Main subroutine to translate the document
Private Sub ephTranslateDoc()
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    
    ' Load XML document
    LoadXmlDocument
    
    ' Translate sections, headers, and footers
    TranslateSections
    
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
End Sub

' Load XML document
Private Sub LoadXmlDocument()
    Dim strXML As String
    strXML = TemplateProject.ThisDocument.Path & "\" & sXmlFileName
    
    If xmlDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xmlDoc.async = False
        xmlDoc.Load (strXML)
    End If
End Sub

' Translate sections, headers, and footers
Private Sub TranslateSections()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim curNode As Object
    Dim sCriteria As String
    
    sCriteria = "//EXPRESSIONS"
    Set curNode = xmlDoc.documentElement.SelectSingleNode(sCriteria)
    
    If Not curNode Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
            TranslateNode curNode, ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Range
            ' Translate other header/footer sections if needed
            TranslateNode curNode, ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            TranslateNode curNode, ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

        Next i
    End If
End Sub

' Translate nodes in the document
Private Sub TranslateNode(ByRef curNode As Object, ByRef rng As Range)
    Dim expNode As Object
    Dim tNode As Object
    Dim sSearch As String, sReplace As String
    
    For Each expNode In curNode.ChildNodes
        sSearch = ""
        sReplace = ""
        For Each tNode In expNode.ChildNodes
            If tNode.nodeName = strFromLang Then sSearch = tNode.text
            If tNode.nodeName = strToLang Then sReplace = tNode.text
        Next
        If sSearch > "" And sReplace > "" Then replaceText rng, sSearch, sReplace
    Next
End Sub

' Replace text in the document
Private Sub replaceText(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal findText As String, ByVal replaceText As String)
    With rng.Find
        .text = findText
        .Replacement.text = replaceText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    rng.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

I'm no VBA expert, I have only tried various GPT suggestions to no avail.

Comment: What's your goal? What does `translating` mean?

Comment: wdHeaderFooterPrimary - "Returns the header or footer on all pages other than the first page of a document or section."  You may need to expand the types of header/footer you operate on.